# Implementation difference between min-height and max-height property value

Tags: css, w3c

[image]

As we can see in the attached picture, when we apply `min-height: none` is **invalid syntax** while `max-height: none` is **valid syntax**. And `max-height: auto` is **invalid syntax**, `min-height: auto` is **valid syntax**.

But when I looked in to the docs [min-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height), [max-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height), it states:

**none:**

> No limit on the size of the box.

I couldn't find exact implementation detail on **w3c**. *Anyone have idea why is this inverse concept is applied in `min-height` and `max-height` property value?* Or, is this just a browser fault not to implement them?

Someone could say that docs states what the `none` value is and we should not be worried about. But I am asking this because having syntax error in the file could mean to affect performance - though, it's just a little opinion.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-heights -- > *none
(Only on 'max-height') No limit on the height of the box.* The MDN is not very accurate here

Comment: Thanks for the link. And what about the auto?

Comment: here is the new Spec: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#min-size-properties .. the auto is only valid for min-*

Comment: It only mentions that `auto` is applied as initial value.

Comment: in *value:* auto is only for min-height and is the initial one

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks.

Comment: I wanted it to leave. So, I flagged this question to put on community wiki.

Comment: you can always add a wiki answer to your question

Comment: I know that but can we not put question as a wiki? Waiting for moderator attention...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [CSS2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-heights), you can read:

> none
>
> (**Only on 'max-height'**) No limit on the height of the box.

`none` is not a valid value for `min-height` (also `min-width`) and `auto` is not a valid value for both.

---

The `auto` value was introduced in the [Box Sizing Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#min-size-properties) instead of the default `0` value for `min-height` only

> Note: The initial value of auto is new; in [CSS2] the initial value was zero.

The introduction of `auto` value for `min-height`/`min-width` is done because of the Flexbox and CSS Grid where `auto` value will not compute to `0`

> Note: The auto keyword, representing an automatic minimum size, is the new initial value of the min-width and min-height properties. The keyword was previously defined in this specification, **but is now defined in the CSS Sizing module**. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)</sup>

> Note: The auto value of min-width and min-height affects track sizing in the relevant axis similar to how it affects the main size of a flex item. See §6.6 Automatic Minimum Size of Grid Items. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-item-sizing)</sup>

I think we can assume that outside the Flexbox and CSS Grid scope, `auto` will compute to `0`